# In Cognito on iOS, handling new password required doesn't ever reach didCompleteNewPasswordStepWithError

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

I'm trying to implement functionality to respond to FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD on my iOS app that uses AWS Cognito. I used [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764564/in-aws-ios-sdk-how-do-i-handle-force-change-password-user-status/42808845#42808845) which references [this sample code](https://github.com/davidtucker/CognitoSampleApplication/blob/article1/CognitoApplication/ResetPasswordViewController.swift). Right now, my code opens a view controller like it's supposed to; however, once on that view controller, I can't get it to do anything. In the sample code, it seems that when you want to submit the password change request you call `.set` on an instance of `AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityNewPasswordRequiredDetails>`, yet when I do this, the protocol function `didCompleteNewPasswordStepWithError` is never called. Interestingly, the other protocol function `getNewPasswordDetails` is called quickly after `viewDidLoad` and I can't tell why. I believe this shouldn't be called until the user has entered their new password, etc and should be in response to `.set` but I could be wrong.

My code is pretty identical to the sample code and that SO post, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

My relevant AppDelegate code is here:

```
extension AppDelegate: AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate {

    func startNewPasswordRequired() -> AWSCognitoIdentityNewPasswordRequired {

        //assume we are presenting from login vc cuz where else would we be presenting that from
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let presentVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.visibleViewController
            TransitionHelperFunctions.presentResetPasswordViewController(viewController: presentVC!)
            print(1)
        }

        var vcToReturn: ResetPasswordViewController?
        returnVC { (vc) in
            vcToReturn = vc
            print(2)
        }
        print(3)
        return vcToReturn!

    }

    //put this into its own func so we can call it on main thread
    func returnVC(completion: @escaping (ResetPasswordViewController) -> () ) {

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ResetPassword", bundle: nil)
            let resetVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResetPasswordViewController") as? ResetPasswordViewController
            completion(resetVC!)
        }

    }
}
```

My relevant ResetPasswordViewController code is here:

```
class ResetPasswordViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBAction func resetButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        var userAttributes: [String:String] = [:]
        userAttributes["given_name"] = firstNameField.text!
        userAttributes["family_name"] = lastNameField.text!

        let details = AWSCognitoIdentityNewPasswordRequiredDetails(proposedPassword: self.passwordTextField.text!, userAttributes: userAttributes)
        self.newPasswordCompletion?.set(result: details)

    }

}

extension ResetPasswordViewController: AWSCognitoIdentityNewPasswordRequired {

    func getNewPasswordDetails(_ newPasswordRequiredInput: AWSCognitoIdentityNewPasswordRequiredInput, newPasswordRequiredCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityNewPasswordRequiredDetails>) {

        self.newPasswordCompletion = newPasswordRequiredCompletionSource

    }

    func didCompleteNewPasswordStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error as? NSError {
                print("error")
                print(error)
            } else {
                // Handle success, in my case simply dismiss the view controller
                SCLAlertViewHelperFunctions.displaySuccessAlertView(timeoutValue: 5.0, title: "Success", subTitle: "You can now login with your new passowrd", colorStyle: Constants.UIntColors.emeraldColor, colorTextButton: Constants.UIntColors.whiteColor)

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Hello, i can't answer to your question but, if you can change some of your code i suggest to use this library https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/ios/start?ref=amplify-iOS-btn that simplify a lot the interaction with AWS cognito. Give it a try! :)

Comment: I agree with @Alessandro. Moving to AWSMobileClient Auth is a much better developer experience.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't switch at this time although we would like to. @Don do you have any advice on making do with Cognito?

Comment: Why can't you switch? AWSMobileClient makes it so easy to work with Cognito.

Comment: @Don our app is already built with Cognito (entirely except for this one bit we're adding on late) and we don't have time to switch right now

Comment: @blorsch AWSMobileClient is a framework the interact with cognito, you should do it. Try to implement only this functionality with that framework