# How to prompt user to forceChangePassword in case its the first login to the Cognito from App

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using 2.33.0 of CognitoUserProvider i do not find the authchallenge method in iOS as in Android. I need to check if its the first login of user after the account creation and navigate him to the Reset the temeprory password screen. How do i achieve this.

[In AWS iOS SDK, how do I handle FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD User Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764564/in-aws-ios-sdk-how-do-i-handle-force-change-password-user-status)

I have tried the above method  in the link in swiftUI but I see that the delegate methods aren't being called